# Why is it that when i call setContentOffset for scroll to top tableView, sometimes it goes half way or so?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to scroll tableview back to top but when i call this:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

Sometimes it works and scrolls all the way to the top, but it also oddly doesn't go all the way up.

Comment: Why are you not using "scrollToRowAtIndexPath" method to scroll to top. It is preferable one

Comment: from where are you calling this? and why have you assigned negative value to `y offset` ?

Answer (score 1):

try one of these,

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

Or

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can also use:

```
[mainTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

Or

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Or

```
NSIndexPath* top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:0];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:top atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

edit your

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Like below,

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    static UIViewController *previousController = nil;
    if (previousController == viewController) {
        // the same tab was tapped a second time
        if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollToTop)]) {
            [viewController scrollToTop];
        }
    }
    previousController = viewController;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I still get the issue of it not going up all the way.

Comment: Sometimes it goes up all the way, and other times it stops randomly at a random point. Any idea?

Comment: when do you want to scroll table view? @farhan

Comment: its when didSelectViewController is called for the TabBar

Comment: you have this method in your code, '- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController'? @farhan

Comment: Yes in a custom TabBarController class.

Comment: whats the point of this line `if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollToTop)])`